# Give an inequality condition for which $f < 0$ and $f' < 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = -x + \int_0^\tau k(\mu)\mathrm{e}^{x\mu}\mathrm{d}\mu$, and $k:[0,\tau]\to\mathbb{R}_+$. What is the necessary (and sufficient if possible) condition such that $\exists \nu_0 \in [0, \infty)$, and $\nu_1 \in [0, \nu_0)$ for which $\forall \nu \in (\nu_1, \nu_0)$ $f(\nu) \leq 0$ and $f'(\nu) \leq 0$ holds.

**My progress so far:**

Write the first order derivative of $f$: $f'(x) = -1 + \int_0^\tau \mu k(\mu)\mathrm{e}^{x\mu}\mathrm{d}\mu$.
Write the second order derivative of $f$: $f''(x) = \int_0^\tau \mu^2 k(\mu)\mathrm{e}^{x\mu}\mathrm{d}\mu$.
We can see that $f''(x) > 0 \quad \forall x > 0$, which means that $f'$ is strict increasing.

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = \infty$, so $f'(0) < 0$ must be true, in which case $\exists \nu_0 \in (0,\infty)$ for which $f'(\nu_0) = 0$. This means that $f'(x) < 0$ on $(0, \nu_0)$ and $f'(x) > 0$ on $(\nu_0, \infty)$.

Now onto $f$: from the previous relations we know that $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(0, \nu_0)$ and strictly increasing on $(\nu_0, \infty)$, and $f$ is convex on the entire interval. $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$, and $f(0) = \int_0^\tau k(\mu)\mathrm{d}\mu > 0$, so the condition $f(\nu) < 0$ could only be sattisfied if I could prove that $f(\nu_0) < 0$, which would mean that $\exists \nu_1 \in [0, \nu_0)$, and $f < 0$ on $(\nu_1, \nu_0)$.

So far I couldn't find a condition which would be sufficient for both $f < 0$ and $f' < 0$, or I just can't see it through.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.